# Suppressing open/collapsing behavior when space pressed int accordion with knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, accordion

I have an jQuery UI Accordion with an input field in the accordion header. 
The input field is bound to an observable `title`. 
All works fine until I try enter a space in my title. 
Pressing space makes the accordion item open/collapse.

My HTML:

```html
<input class="title" name="title" data-bind="textInput:title"/>
```

In viewModel:

```
this.title = ko.observable();
```

I have tried switching to binding of type `value` and adding a `valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'` at the end of the data-bind, to no avail.

How can I suppress this behavior?

Comment: It would help if you extended the code in your question to reproduce your scenario, preferably with a Stack Snippet. (PS. Are you using [*jQuery UI's* accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)?)